# Apache URL rewriting and wildcard subdomain handling

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a PHP newbie and I'm creating a web app where users can register and can get a subdomain. I've already done the registration part, but I want to do one more thing which I can't figure out.
So when a user browses to example.domain.com if user 'example' already registered then he should get the page from domain.com/users/example/ but if the username is not taken it should write "This domain is not registered yet. blabla"

How could I do this?
thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: i dont see what's the relation between the title and the not-question in your question

Comment: @Qchmpqs because you use wildcards for the url rewrites to be able to provide the information to the php script to be able to verify whether the user exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what your looking for?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /   

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /users/%1/ [L]

RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Then you could manage the display part within the php file and if no user associated then redirect.

You also have to add a wildcard comment to the httpd.conf file for the domain so that is supports wildcard subdomains:

```
ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

User.php would be something like:

```
<?
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM db WHERE username = 'mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[username])'") > 0)
{
    echo "User Exists";
}
else
{
    header("Location: /register.php?username=$_GET[username]");
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. i've updated my .htaccess file but it's giving an internal server error.

Comment: I slightly changed the above, remember to change domain.com to your domain and you also need to add the wildcard for it to work.

Comment: it's still throwing an error. i checked the apache log, it hase problems with the first rule.

Comment: Changed once again, any luck?

Comment: It's still not working. RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^user/([a-zA-Z9-0-_]+)/$' this is the exact error.

Comment: It seems that this doesn`t work either... It gets rewritten to user.php?username=$1 even if there is the directory in /users

Comment: ([a-zA-Z9-0-_]+) the 0 and 9 being the wrong way round could be the problem `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)`

Comment: there is no error now. the problem is that it does not redirect the unexistent domains to  user.php?username=$1

Answer (score -1):

First, create the default page that has the message "This domain is not registered yet. blabla". Call this registration.html

I am assuming you have a database storing the registered domains.

search database to see if example.domain.com is registered.

```
if(example.domain.com registered)
http_redirect (domain.com/users/example/);
else  
http_redirect (registration.html);
```